# cloudfront cache pattern for root object, one page app, or index.html

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront

We are running a one page app and having issues with cloudfront's caching service. Our .css and .js files are hashed on build so duration of the cache for those do not matter and can be unlimited. The issue is with caching the index.html page. If we set the cache for index.html to 5 minutes accessing the website via ur/index.html#/route works for the expected length. However, the cache for url/#/route does not work instead caching this index.html file for a long period of time. 
We've attempted these patterns so far

```
*.html
*
index.html
*/
```

# is not accepted in the pattern and is an invalid symbol. We tried #* and it is invalid.

Any advise would be great. Thanks!

Update:
We are now using /*. It seems / might have worked for the root object as well. Upon investigation it seemed that our old global cache was set to 24hrs and we wouldn't see these changes until the next day. Gotta love debugging cache's...

Answer (score 2):

The path pattern for matching `https://example.com/#/route` is simply `/`.

`#/route` is called the URL *fragment* and the web server/cache does not see the fragment, so you would not include any of this in the path pattern.

Move this path pattern to the top of the list of cache behaviors -- they are evaluated in order, and the first match is used.